# Could Stossel have sued Facebook (for defamation) in a state other than California?

Tags: united-states, defamation, jurisdiction

Interestingly, California seems to a place where it's harder to win a defamation lawsuit because the 9th Circuit has more or less "overridden", or at least issued a more clear test of opinion-vs-fact (in [*Standing Committee v. Yagman*](https://casetext.com/case/standing-committee-v-yagman), 55 F.3d 1430, 1439, 9th Cir. 1995) compared the SCOTUS' much debated (and [criticized](https://www.honigman.com/media/site_files/1601_Niehoff_opinions_implications_confusions.pdf)) *Milkovich v. Lorain Journal Co.*, 1990. Facebook/Meta's [motion to dismiss](https://storage.courtlistener.com/recap/gov.uscourts.cand.385450/gov.uscourts.cand.385450.27.0.pdf) specifically quotes from *Standing Committee v. Yagman* in their defense that FB fact-check labels are "protected opinion" (under the 9th Circuit) even though SCOTUS might not recognize that category as such/distinct.

So, I'm curious to know: does a resident of New York like Stossel has any choice of where to sue a company like Facebook/Meta for defamation? Or are they are forced to sue them in the company's home state, in this case California?
(I've looked at a [2019 review](https://ir.lawnet.fordham.edu/flr/vol88/iss2/11/), but it's unclear to me what the situation is like in the 2nd Circuit, which covers New York. So, venue may or may not make a difference, in this case. But some [Bill Cosby] "liar" lawsuits that were barred in the 3rd circuit were allowed in the 1st, for instance. Which seem at least vaguely relevant in that they involved labelling, albeit someone, rather than a just a statement.)